# Why does the wallpaper color intensity change in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, desktop-background, gnome-color-manager

[image: This is the screenshot of the picture that I set as my wallpaper]

[image: This the screenshot I took after setting it as my wallpaper. There's this difference in the intensity of the red color. The same thing happens with other wallpapers as well.]
I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Whenever I set a picture as my wallpaper, the color intensity changes for some reason and I can't figure out why. How do I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Do you have Night Light on? (See Settings/Screens, right tab on top)

Comment: No, not right now, not at the time of taking the screenshots.